# How to fix text length in a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm tryin' to create a simple calculator using JS. 
I'm using a paragraph tag as a display and the problem is that the text can go beyond the line.

My calculator:

[image: sccreen1]

But when I enter more than like 12 buttons this happens:

[image: screen2]

They way I'm adding numbers looks like:

```
    $('#5').click(function() {
  $("#mainline").text(function(i, oldtext) {
    return oldtext.replace(/^0$/, '') + '5';
  });
});
```

I tried to put all buttons in a loop that will check the length of the paragraph tag and if it's more than 12 then:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("button").disabled = true
```

But I didn't work. What should I do?

HTML:

```
<div class='calculator'>
          <div class='lines'><p id="mainline">0</p></div>

          <div id="row1">

            <button id='AC'>AC</button>
            <button id='pm'><sup>+</sup>/<sub>-</sub></button>
            <button>%</button>
            <button id='dvd'>/</button>

          </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .calculator {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 37%;
  padding-top: 7%;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

#mainline {
  border: 3px solid #FF9500;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Well what do you want it to do if it goes too much? do you want the text to be smaller?

Comment: Can you add your HTML / CSS, add a snippet, thanks

Comment: @SheshankS. I want the buttons to be blocked

Comment: @Desiigner what if the result is too much?

Comment: @SheshankS.well, I guess I didn't think of it. I think it'd be smarter to lower the font-size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple things to think of, as I read in comments.

But here is a suggestion that may be of interest: CSS [`direction:rtl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) and [`text-overflow:ellipsis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)...

```js
$("#test").on("keyup",function(){
  $("#display").text($(this).val());
});
```

```css
#display{
  /* Just for this demo */
  height:1em;
  width:8em;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:0.4em;
  
  /* suggestion */
  direction: rtl;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type in! <input id="test"><br>
Result: <div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: yeah I understood what you mean, but adding this CSS properties to my paragraph doesn't make any changes. Does it happen because my display is not a div?

Comment: I'm not sure... Are you talking about `<p id="mainline">`?

Comment: yeah, exactly. Should make it a div?

Comment: Sure... I hope you did right after that comment. Maybe certainly the `width` of a `p` is different from a `div`.  Why that `p` for anyway?

Comment: HTML and CSS are *very close* when about tweeky display usage. Look for a script when user input is involved.... And you can narrow it real tight based on UI events. ;)